# Unable to integrate Firebase RemoteConfig as a dependency

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I am trying to add **firebase-config** into my project as dependency I tried using the Firebase tools and as it configures my dependencies and I synchronize it I get error.

> Could not find firebase-config.jar
>   (com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.8.0). Searched in the
>   following locations:
>   https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-config/11.8.0/firebase-config-11.8.0.jar

**App Level dependency:**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.3.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26+'
    compile 'com.github.Mariovc:ImagePicker:1.0.5'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26+'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26+'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:26+'
    compile 'com.fenchtose:tooltip:0.1.5'
    compile 'com.github.tobiasbuchholz:circularviewpager:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.+'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'it.sephiroth.android.library.targettooltip:target-tooltip-library:1.3.15'
    compile 'com.github.vajro:MaterialDesignLibrary:1.6'
    compile 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.3.2'
    compile 'me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar:library:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.matthew-tamlin:sliding-intro-screen:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.akexorcist:localizationactivity:1.2.2'
    compile 'in.gauriinfotech:commons:1.0.8'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.8.0'
    debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.1'
    releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.1'
    testCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.1'
    compile 'com.joanzapata.iconify:android-iconify-fontawesome:2.2.2'
    compile 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.21@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:26+'
    compile 'com.github.gturedi:stateful-layout:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.florent37:expansionpanel:1.0.7'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }


}
```

**Top Level Build:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }


    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, first you need to remove the following lines of code:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.+'
```

And the change all the following lines of code:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.8.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.0'
```

Also please don't forget to change this line of code:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

More informations [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) and [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup).